# Pandas: how to read certain file type in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently working on the data set from this [link](https://github.com/smarthi/UnivOfWashington-Machine-Learning/tree/master/MLFoundations/week4/people_wiki.gl). But I am unable to read these files from Pandas? Has anyone tried to play with such files?

I am trying the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("m_4549381c276b46c6.0000")
```

But I get the following error

```
Error tokenizing data. C error: Buffer overflow caught - possible malformed input file.
```

Comment: Why do you think this is a CSV file?

Answer (score 1):

It's an SFrame, not a CSV; you need GraphLab, not pandas. They show you how to load it in the [attendant notebook](https://github.com/smarthi/UnivOfWashington-Machine-Learning/blob/master/MLFoundations/week4/document-retrieval.ipynb):

> graphlab.SFrame(path)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this particular dataset, but try adding
`encoding='utf-8'` to the `read_csv` call.

```
df = pd.read_csv("m_4549381c276b46c6.0000",encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: The error message given in the question is not typical for an encoding problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a database file. You cannot directly open it in pandas. You can use a software in order to convert it first to a csv or something that can be opened in pandas. One such application is [here](http://dbfconv.com/)